# NSMutableData to Int

Tags: iphone, nsmutabledata

I have a call to a URL and receive back a 0 or 1 on fail or success.  I have my data in a NSMutableData *data; object.

I get the data, but now want to see if it's a 1 or 0. How do I do this? Do I need to get the bytes?

Thanks

Comment: Code is always welcomed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to convert the `NSData` to an `NSString` first. Then you can use the `intValue` method on `NSString` to convert it to an integer.

For example:

```
NSString* response = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: 
    NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
int value = [response intValue];
```